# Can Animation objects be shared and reused?

Tags: android, animation

Consider the following:

```
Animation foo = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(parentActivity, R.anim.scale_up);
```

With the respective XML resource being defined as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator"
     android:fillBefore="true"
     android:fillAfter="false"
     android:fillEnabled="true">

    <scale
        android:fromXScale="0.00"
        android:fromYScale="0.00"
        android:toXScale="1.00"
        android:toYScale="1.00"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="50"
        android:repeatCount="0"/>

</set>
```

Can animation objects created in this manner `Animation foo` be applied to multiple view objects?

```
view1.startAnimation(foo);
view2.startAnimation(foo);
view3.startAnimation(foo);
```

What happens when `view1.clearAnimation();`? Do the animations stop for other views too?

Is the `Animation foo` object something that stores state and thus should not be applied to multiple views (e.g. bouncy button effects)

or is it just an object that holds some static definitions of the parsed XML file and can be readily created once before being reused multiple times?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9217305/6891563

Comment: @Khemraj And? Can it be shared or not?

Comment: No, you should not share animations. Cause each view has independent animation and callbacks.